# What can the order of the element be in the infinite group?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G$ be a group and $|G|=\infty$. Is it always true that every element in $G$ except the identity $e$ has order $\infty$? Can it be the case that every element in $G$ has finite order? Can it be the case that some element in $G$ has finite order, while some infinite order?

The only examples for infinite groups I know is $\Bbb Z,~\Bbb R,~\Bbb C$, which every element in $G$ except the identity $e$ has order $\infty$. However, I wonder in general what situation can it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first and third questions have already been answered (the third was answered implicitly - think more about $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ ...).

For the second question, think about the following:

- If I take the direct product of a bunch of groups where every element has finite order, then in the result every element has finite order. *(Why?)*
- OK, now remember that *we can take the direct product of an infinite collection of groups* ...

---

If you want to avoid the language of direct products, think about the operation of [symmetric difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference) on the set of sets of natural numbers *(or if you prefer, the [XOR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or) operation on infinite binary strings)*. Show that this is a group, and that every element has finite order; it's trivially infinite, so this then gives an example.

This group, by the way, is just the infinite direct product of $\mathbb{N}$-many copies of $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. But the description above might be helpful in thinking about it more concretely at first.

Comment: Wow, I never heard the infinite direct product before.

Comment: @Eric I've added a bit to my answer, given that you haven't seen infinite direct products before.

Answer (score 3):

I would like to give an answer refering to your statement "The only examples for infinite groups I know is $\Bbb Z,~\Bbb R,~\Bbb C$". From linear algebra you remember perhaps also the general linear group $GL_n(K)$ for, say, $K=\Bbb Z,~\Bbb Q,~\Bbb R,~\Bbb C$.
Then the $2\times 2$ matrices
$$
\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \cr 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix},\; 
\begin{pmatrix} -1 & 0 \cr 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix},\;
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \cr 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix},\; 
\begin{pmatrix} -1 & 0 \cr 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix},\;\cdots
$$
have order $2$ in the infinite groups $GL_n(K)$. On the other hand,
$$
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \cr 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
$$
has infinite order.

Comment: Thanks for the reminding! These examples are really I should have notice.

Answer (score 3):

$\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ also answers all your questions ($2$ a little indirectly). Note that $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ is infinite.

1. No, not true, $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ being an example: $\overline{\frac{1}{2}}$ has order $2$.
2. Take $G_F < \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ as the subgroup of all elements of finite order. $G_F$ is still infinite (containing for instance $\overline{\frac{1}{i}}$ for all $i \in \mathbb{N}$, which are different elements). Note that for any abelian group $G$, $G_F$ is a subgroup.
3. $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ has elements of finite order (any class of a rational) and also infinite order (any class of a irrational).

Noting that $(\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z},\overline{+}) \simeq (S^1,\cdot)$ is also an instructive geometrical way to see the above facts.

Answer (score 2):

Infinite groups can have elements of finite order. Consider $\Bbb Z_2\times\Bbb Z$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can have elements of finite order. For example look at $O_2(\mathbb{R})$, the orthogonal $2\times2$ matrices. They form a group and the element with $-1$ on the diagonal and $0$ as other entries is an element of this (infinite) group with order $2$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $\mathbb Z_n \times \mathbb Z$. It has elements with finite and also infinite orders. Also consider $\mathbb Z_2^{\infty}$.

Comment: Thanks. What is $\mathbb Z_2^{\infty}$ by the way?

Comment: It has two elements. One of them is identity and other one has order $2$. It is also a cyclic group of order $2$

Comment: So isn't it just $\Bbb Z_2$ under the meaning of isomorphism?

Comment: Eric, $\mathbb{Z}_2^\infty$ denotes the direct product of infinitely many copies of $\mathbb{Z}_2$. (I think GhD misread your comment.)

Comment: @Eric no I multiplied $\mathbb Z_2$ infinitely many time.

Comment: @NoahSchweber You are right I did :))